# Redirecting all requests to https://

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

Our website is running on a nginx server and our .htaccess has following code

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

When I type `domain.com` it redirects to `https://www.domain.com` but when we type `www.domain.com` it remains unsecured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Now the pattern matches both www and non-www  requests for the domain.com